# What will happen to the application if database memory is full in android?

Tags: android

If phone memory is full, i'm trying to load data into my application database. Actually application create his db file in phone memory data path such as **data/data/[package name]/databases/**. What will be happen in this stage?

And

If my android phone is 1GB internal memory. How many memory space allocate to application database location?

Comment: Y cant u make use of External Storage Directory as the db file takes more memory because all devices cant have 1 GB of internal memory. While programming, consider the devices with less internal memory is a must.

Comment: @AvadhaniY, Application creates his db file only in system memory(as data/data/[package name]/database).

Comment: Are you mean that application stores its own db file in external storage? if my app install in internal memory, now where db file stores?

Comment: Most probably, an I/O exception will occur if there is no enough space.

Comment: If your application installs in internal/external storage, you can write a program such that the db file will be stored in any type of storage independent of where the application is installed.